# cURL POST to Cisco Spark API with JSON data on command line results in an error (when using Mac OS X terminal)

Tags: shell, curl

I'm attempting to POST JSON data to the Cisco Spark API using cURL.  I want to include the JSON data in the -d parameter on the command line.  My command is as follows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "$header" -i -v -X POST -d '{ "roomId": "$roomid", "text": "$message" }' https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages
```

I can get the POST to work if I pass the name of a file containing the JSON data in the -d parameter, but I'd prefer to be able to do it on the command line.  Identifiers in the command above that are prefixed with the '$' are environment variables in my c shell.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `"` to expand variables. So your request should looks like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "$header" -i -v -X POST \
    -d "{ \"roomId\": \"$roomid\", \"text\": \"$message\" }" \
    https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I was thinking similarly, but when I switch to this method the parser complains of an unmatched `"`

Comment: Neither of them contain quotes: `roomid = Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vZDM2MzgyOTAtMmRmZC0xMWU4LWEyYmItODE4M2Q5NmFkODFj` ******||******** `message = Hello Spark, from Ron Coe`

Comment: How looks like _parser complains of an unmatched "_? Because I got response from server (invalid authorization) with command in answer.

Comment: Thank you again for your input.  I have confirmed that this is a bug in the way that the c shell on Mac OS X parses input.  I sshED into one of my Ubuntu virtual machines and was able to execute the command as expected.

Comment: Definitely the C Shell parser.  The bash on Mac OS X also processes the command line appropriately.